# Does $ \vec x=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{smallmatrix}\right)$ lie in the Image of $L$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, linear-transformations, vector-analysis

I have the following linear transformation:

$$L: \mathbb{R^3}  \to \mathbb{R^3}, \begin{pmatrix}a \\ b \\ c  \end{pmatrix} \mapsto \begin{pmatrix}a-c \\ 0 \\ b  \end{pmatrix}$$

and I have to check if $ \vec x=\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 1  \end{pmatrix}$ lies in the Image of L. I know that the image is defined as $Im(L):={L(\vec v)\in\mathbb{R^3} | \vec v} \in\mathbb{R^3}$ but I can't figure out how to check if  $\vec x$ lies in the image.

Comment: Ask yourself a simpler question to see if you understand the term "image". If $f(x)=x^2$, will $1 \in \text{Image}_f$, will $-1 \in \text{Image}_f$?

Comment: From my understanding, the values you pick for $a,b,c$ is the premímage of the output values, in this case $a-c,0,b$. So from that I think that I have to work backwards, because I already have the output values but I need to check if these values can actually be achieved from the linear transformation. @AnuragA

Comment: Yes, indeed. You want to see if $a-c=1$ and so on.

Comment: Standard notation is that $x \mapsto f(x)$, so use the command `\mapsto`

Answer (score 1):

$L\begin{pmatrix}a \\ b \\ c  \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 1  \end{pmatrix}\implies a - c = 1, b = 1$. Take $(a,b,c) = (1,1,0)$, and the answer is yes ! Note that there are many choices because, say $c$ is any real number.

Comment: a=2 and $c=1$ works too, so $(2,1,1)$ is another solutions. In general $a-c=1 \implies a=1+c$ and if we call $c= \alpha $ a parameter, then the vectors of the form 
$$ (a,b,c) = (1+\alpha, 1 , \alpha )^T, \; \; \; \alpha \in \mathbb{R} $$

will get mapped to the vector $(1,0,1)^T$

Comment: That's what I was working on but I have a small question. You found that $a-c=0$ but how does that mean that $(a,b,c)=(1,1,0)$?

Comment: Because $L(a,b,c)^T = (a-c,0,b)^T = (1,0,1)^T $ and now compare componentwise